# Spring Cloud Data Flow global properties for Composed Tasks

Tags: spring, properties, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to pass **global** properties into **Composed tasks**. When I specify each and every job, it works, but there is configuration **duplicity**. I tried multiple approaches, but the properties are not set correctly.

My project (jar) contains **multiple Spring Batch** jobs. Which one is executed depends on the java argument. The CSDF task looks like this:

```
download: my-task 'COMPLETED'->status_ok: my-task 'FAILED'->status_error: my-task
```

[image]

There is also an option in SCDF UI for adding these global properties in the **Global** column:
[image]

which translates to `app.*.property=value`.

However, this does not work and properties are not sent over in the environment variables in each task.

Since I am using a database for my project, I need to specify datasource for the SCDF and also for JPA. Hence I am overriding **DefaultTaskConfigurer**.
Configuration that works looks like this:

```
app.my-task.download.spring.batchdatasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
app.my-task.download.spring.batchdatasource.password=rootpw
app.my-task.download.spring.batchdatasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/dataflow
app.my-task.download.spring.batchdatasource.username=root

app.my-task.download.spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
app.my-task.download.spring.datasource.password=pw
app.my-task.download.spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/csv
app.my-task.download.spring.datasource.username=root
 
app.my-task.status_ok.spring.batchdatasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
app.my-task.status_ok.spring.batchdatasource.password=rootpw
app.my-task.status_ok.spring.batchdatasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/dataflow
app.my-task.status_ok.spring.batchdatasource.username=root
 
app.my-task.status_ok.spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
app.my-task.status_ok.spring.datasource.password=pw
app.my-task.status_ok.spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/csv
app.my-task.status_ok.spring.datasource.username=root
 
app.my-task.status_error.spring.batchdatasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
app.my-task.status_error.spring.batchdatasource.password=rootpw
app.my-task.status_error.spring.batchdatasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/dataflow
app.my-task.status_error.spring.batchdatasource.username=root

app.my-task.status_error.spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
app.my-task.status_error.spring.datasource.password=pw
app.my-task.status_error.spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/csv
app.my-task.status_error.spring.datasource.username=root
```

**batchdatasource.*** properties are for the SCDF and **datasource.*** is for my personal use. This works like a charm, both datasources are initialized.

Also, run arguments look like this:

```
app.download.0=--jobName=download
app.status_error.0=--status=Error
app.status_error.1=--jobName=status
app.status_ok.0=--status=Ok
app.status_ok.1=--jobName=status
```

But as you can see, there is a lot of duplicity. I tried to do it this way

```
app.*.spring.batchdatasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
app.*.spring.batchdatasource.password=rootpw
app.*.spring.batchdatasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/dataflow
app.*.spring.batchdatasource.username=root

app.*.spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
app.*.spring.datasource.password=pw
app.*.spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/csv
app.*.spring.datasource.username=root
```

and this way

```
app.my-task.*.spring.batchdatasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
app.my-task.*.spring.batchdatasource.password=rootpw
app.my-task.*.spring.batchdatasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/dataflow
app.my-task.*.spring.batchdatasource.username=root

app.my-task.*.spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
app.my-task.*.spring.datasource.password=pw
app.my-task.*.spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/csv
app.my-task.*.spring.datasource.username=root
```

but none of this works. What am I doing wrong ?

As you can see, properties were not set for this task execution.
[image]